# How can i make my program reactive in swift with RxSwift

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-programming, rx-swift, eureka-forms

hey !!!

I'm on OSX, the last one, using the last xcode version, and the last version of iOS :)

I've some problems to implement mvvm and reactive programming in my test project.
For reactive i'm using RxSwift libraries from here [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)

```
// so here my implementation of SettingsVC.swift

import UIKit
import SpeedLog
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
import Eureka

class SettingsVC: FormViewController {
    let viewModel = SettingsVM()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupFormer()
    }

    func setupFormer() {
        //        self.tableView?
        //            .rx_setDelegate(self)
        //            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        //        
        //        // Setup Observer


        self.setRegisterAndLoginRows()
        self.setProfileRow()
    }

    func setRegisterAndLoginRows() {
        self.form
            +++= ButtonRow("connectDisconnect") {
                $0.title = "Connexion"
                } .onCellSelection { row in
                    SpeedLog.print((row.cell.textLabel?.text)! + " called")
                    UIViewController.pushModal(self, pushModalTo: PushModalTo.Connection)
            }

            <<< ButtonRow("registration") {
                $0.title = "Inscription"
                } .onCellSelection { row in
                    SpeedLog.print((row.cell.textLabel?.text)! + " called")
                    //UIViewController.pushModal(self, pushModalTo: PushModalTo.Connection)
        }
    }

    func setProfileRow() {
        form
            +++= Section("Mon compte")

            <<< LabelRow("profile") {
                $0.title = "Mon profil"
                $0.value = "Non enregistré"
                let cell = $0
                Session.appUser?.username
                    .asObservable()
                    .subscribeNext { username in
                        if let usernameTemp = username {
                            cell.value = usernameTemp
                        }
                    }
                    .addDisposableTo((Session.appUser?.disposeBag)!)
                } .onCellSelection { row in
                    SpeedLog.print((row.cell.textLabel?.text)! + " called")
                    UIViewController.pushView(self, pushSettingsTo: PushSettingsTo.MyProfile)
        }
    }
}

// my SessionManager

import Foundation
import RxSwift

let Session = SessionManager.sharedInstance

class SessionManager {
    static let sharedInstance = SessionManager()

    var appUser: AppUser?

    init() {
        self.appUser = nil
    }
}

// and my class User, because AppUser just inherit from User

import Foundation
import SpeedLog
import RxSwift

class User {
    var username: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var accessToken: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var country: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var created: Variable<NSDate?> = Variable(nil)
    var disabled: Variable<Bool?> = Variable(nil)
    var displayName: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var email: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var emailVerified: Variable<Bool?> = Variable(nil)
    var locale: Variable<LocaleContainer?> = Variable(nil)
    var modified: Variable<NSDate?> = Variable(nil)
    var phoneNumber: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var phoneVerified: Variable<Bool?> = Variable(nil)
    var userID: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    var picture: Variable<UIImage?> = Variable(nil)
    var pictureURL: Variable<String?> = Variable(nil)
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func set(kiiUser: KiiUser) {
        self.username.value = kiiUser.username
        self.accessToken.value = kiiUser.accessToken
        self.country.value = kiiUser.country
        self.created.value = kiiUser.created
        self.disabled.value = kiiUser.disabled
        self.displayName.value = kiiUser.displayName
        self.email.value = kiiUser.email
        self.emailVerified.value = kiiUser.emailVerified
        self.locale.value = kiiUser.locale
        self.modified.value = kiiUser.modified
        self.phoneNumber.value = kiiUser.phoneNumber
        self.phoneVerified.value = kiiUser.phoneVerified
        self.userID.value = kiiUser.userID
        self.picture.value = UIImage()
        self.pictureURL.value = String()
    }
}
```

I've already try to change just the Singleton to Variable() but it doesn't work ..
What i make bad ?
Sorry for my bad english :/

Thanks for your helps

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: i'm trying to update user class and, after connect, update my view controller with the name of user who's just connected :)

Comment: It's ok, i find the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey,

I found a solution to implement Eureka librarie, rxswift, and MVVM, i gonna share it:

SettingsVC

```
import UIKit
import SpeedLog
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
import Eureka

class SettingsVC: FormViewController {

private var viewModel: SettingsVM?
private let disposeBag      = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.initUI()
    self.bindViewModel()
}

func initUI() {
    // Settings form rows
    self.form
        +++=    ButtonRow("connectDisconnect")
        <<<     ButtonRow("registration")

    self.form
        +++=    Section("Mon compte")
        <<<     LabelRow("profile")

}

func bindViewModel() {
    self.viewModel = SettingsVM(form: &self.form, vc: self)
} 
}
```

SettingsVM

```
import Foundation
import SpeedLog
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
import RxViewModel
import Eureka

class SettingsVM: RxViewModel {
// Private
private let disposeBag      = DisposeBag()
let vc:                     SettingsVC
let connectDisconnectRow:   ButtonRow?
let inscriptionRow:         ButtonRow?
let myProfileRow:           LabelRow?

init(inout form: Form, vc: SettingsVC) {
    self.vc = vc
    self.connectDisconnectRow   = form.rowByTag("connectDisconnect")
    self.inscriptionRow         = form.rowByTag("registration")
    self.myProfileRow           = form.rowByTag("profile")
    super.init()

    self.configureCell()
}

func configureCell() {
    // Connexion Disconnect button
    connectDisconnectRow?.baseCell.baseRow.title = "Connexion"
    connectDisconnectRow?.onCellSelection { cell, row in
        SpeedLog.print((row.cell.textLabel?.text)! + " called")
        UIViewController.pushModal(self.vc, pushModalTo: PushModalTo.Connection)
    }

    // Inscription button
    inscriptionRow?.baseCell.baseRow.title = "Inscription"
    inscriptionRow?.onCellSelection { cell, row in
        SpeedLog.print((row.cell.textLabel?.text)! + " called")
        UIViewController.pushModal(self.vc, pushModalTo: PushModalTo.Registration)
    }

    // My profile button
    myProfileRow?.baseCell.baseRow.title = "Mon profil"
    myProfileRow?.baseCell.baseRow.baseValue = "Non enregistré"

    _ = Session.appUser.displayName.asObservable().subscribeNext { displayName in
        if displayName != "" && displayName != nil {
            self.myProfileRow?.baseCell.baseRow.baseValue = displayName
        }
        self.myProfileRow?.baseCell.baseRow.reload()
    }
    myProfileRow?.onCellSelection { cell, row in
        SpeedLog.print((row.cell.textLabel?.text)! + " called")
        UIViewController.pushView(self.vc, pushSettingsTo: PushSettingsTo.MyProfile)
    }
}
}
```

I hope it's gonna help all people who's want to implement that things :)
See ya